# NSData and String in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, stream, nsdata, socketserver

I'm developing an iOS application in Swift 3, and I want to interact via wifi with my RPi,using a Simple Socket Server method. Here in this part of program,

```
@IBAction func ButtoniPhone(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let data : NSData = "C'est l'iPhone".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData
    self.outStream?.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)      
}
```

But I give an error here :

`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>' with an argument list of type '(unsafeRawPointer)'`

Is there anyone who knows a solution?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why are you using `NSData` in Swift? Use `Data`.

Comment: Thanks to replay, How can I use Data in this cas?